# 'Could not convert variant of type (Null) into type (Double)'

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-10

```
if DataModuleGeral.tbHonorariosPERCENT_ADV_ASSIST1.AsFloat = 0 then
begin
  DataModuleGeral.tbHonorariosPERCENT_ADV_ASSIST1.Value := Null;
end;
```

Tenho a rotina acima que quando o calulo da porcentagem é 0 eu tento setar o campo para `Null` para que no banco de dados não fique com o campo em branco...
No `Delphi 7` funciona perfeito e agora no Delphi 10.1 não está funcionando...
Algum sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na atribuição do `null` também já tive problemas a usar o `Value`, então uso o `AsVariant` assim:

```
DataModuleGeral.tbHonorariosPERCENT_ADV_ASSIST1.AsVariant:= Null;
```

Comment: hum... vou testar não tina pensando nisso.

Comment: Funcional Prefeito. Valeu man!